# Cruise Control .Net server unable to detect modifications done on Starteam

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, starteam

I'm using Cruise Control .Net 1.4 for Continuous integration and have installed it on my Windows 2000 desktop. I have Nant 0.85 for the Build. My Source control is in Borland Starteam 2005. I have the .Net 2003 framework installed which I use for creating VB.Net windows applications. I have installed CCNet and I think my CCnet.config file is configured correctly.

The problem that I face is that whenever I change any code and check in Starteam, the modifications are not getting detected by the CCNet server and so I cannot trigger my builds on the basis of modifications. I have to rely on forcebuild for that. But using forcebuild every 1 minute is not acceptable for my project. I want the trigger to be based on modifications. I.e. as soon as a change is detected on Starteam, the build should automatically take place.

My CCNet.config file is this:

```
<workingDirectory>C:\Documents and Settings\uj0011637\Desktop\StarteamCruiseControl\CCNet17Nov08</workingDirectory>
<webURL>http://172.24.120.37/ccnet</webURL>

<triggers>
    <intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="120" buildCondition="ForceBuild" initialSeconds="120"/>         
    </triggers>


<sourcecontrol type="starteam">
   <executable>C:\Program Files\Borland\StarTeam Cross-Platform Client 2005 R2\stcmd.exe</executable>
   <project>DEL_CA_ROBOTS\Tools\CCNet17Nov08</project>
   <username>600513221</username>
   <password>car0b0ts</password>
   <host>oscar.nat.bt.com</host>
   <port>51234</port>
   <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>
   <timeout units="minutes">10</timeout>
</sourcecontrol>


<tasks>
      <!-- Configure NAnt to compile the updated files -->c:\
    <nant>
    <executable>C:\Documents and Settings\uj0011637\Desktop\Cruise Control\nant\nant-0.85\bin\NAnt.exe</executable>
    <baseDirectory>C:\Documents and Settings\uj0011637\Desktop\StarteamCruiseControl\CCNet17Nov08</baseDirectory>
    <nologo>false</nologo>
    <buildFile>CCNet17Nov08.build</buildFile>
    <logger>NAnt.Core.XmlLogger</logger>
    <buildTimeoutSeconds>1200</buildTimeoutSeconds>
    </nant>
</tasks>


<!--Publishers will be done after the build has completed-->
 <publishers>
  <xmllogger>
    <logDir>C:\Documents and Settings\uj0011637\Desktop\StarteamCruiseControl\Log</logDir>
  </xmllogger>
 </publishers>

 <modificationDelaySeconds>10</modificationDelaySeconds>
```

And my build file is this:

```
<target name="clean" description="Delete all previously compiled binaries.">
    <delete>
        <fileset>
```

```
            <include name="**/bin/${project::get-name()}.dll" />
            <include name="**/obj/**" />
            <include name="**/*.user" />
        </fileset>
    </delete>
</target>
```

```
<target name="rebuild" dependsontarget="clean, build ">
<zip zipfile="${project::get-name()}.zip"  verbose="true">
    <fileset>
    <include name="**/bin/*.dll" />
    <include name="**/bin/*.exe" />
    </fileset>
    <fileset>
    <include name="*.aspx" />
    <include name="*.css" />
    <include name="*.config" />
    <include name="*.js" />
    <include name="*.asax" />
    <include name="**.txt" />
    <include name="**.vb" />
    <include name="**.vbproj" />
    <include name="**.user" />
    <include name="**.sln" />
    <include name="**.suo" />
    <include name="**.resx" />

    </fileset>
    <fileset prefix="SQL">
    <include name="*.sql" />
    </fileset>
</zip>



</target>

<target name="unit_test" description="Run unit tests.">

     <exec program="${nunit.dir}\nunit-console.exe" commandline="bin/${prjname}.exe /xml=${prjname}.xml /nologo" />

   </target>

    <target name="build.Console">

    <solution configuration="release" solutionfile="CCNet17Nov08.sln">

    </solution>

    <property name="expected.output" value="bin/${prjname}.exe"/>
    <fail unless="${file::exists(expected.output)}">Output file doesn't exist in ${expected.output}</fail>

</target>
```

Can anybody please guide me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I had challenges in understanding the documentation for installing and configuring CruiseControl.Net with StarTeam as the souce control in a Vista system running IIS 7. Finally I have successfully set up cruise control to work. I am listing the steps to get it working.

Step 1:Grab a copy of CruiseControl.Net from here. Run the setup. As a part of the install, the setup installs the ccnet server and a webdashboard.

Step 2:Once installed, to get the webdashboard up and running, fire your browser and type. http://localhost/ccnet (this is the default virtual directory on install. This points to the $InstallFolder/webdashboard folder in your build server. If the system is running IIS5 or 6, then you will see a CruiseControl.Net page, in IIS7, an 500 error is thrown. To resolve this issue, proceed to Step 3, if no issue was encountered, proceed to Step 4.

Step 3:Run the followin command as an administrator. Note: Here ccnet is the virtual directory which points to the physical location of webdashboard in the system.

%SystemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd migrate config "Default Web Site/ccnet"

Once the command is run, then just restart iis and browse to http://localhost/ccnet. It should show the CruiseControl.Net dashboard.

Step 4:Next step is to configure the ccnet server. Open the ccnet.config file located in the ’server’ folder of the install directory to edit.

Project Section:

Define the project section. The project name can be any identifier not necessarily your project name. This will be used by CruiseControl.Net to recognize your project.

Source Control Section

In my case, the source control was StarTeam. Various properties like login credentials, project etc, are to be set.

Executable:Path to the ’stcmd.exe’ the Star Team command line utility.

Project:The name of the Project as defined in Star Team, that has to be extracted.

UserName, Password, Host, Port:Star Team Server connection setttings.

Path:Path from which files have to extracted from StarTeam. Example: Consider the Project root folder in StarTeam is “Test”. Let the project and solution files lie in the hierarchy “Test\TestProject\MyProject”. To pull the project files and solution from this location, specify “Test” for project and “TestProject\MyProject” for path.

Override Folder Working Directory:Path to which the files from Star Team are to be checked out for the build. If not specified, the original working folder specified in the StarTeam will be used to extract the files.

Auto Get Source:Specifying this to ‘true’ will allow CruiseControl.Net to automatically check out files from StarTeam

fileHistoryRegEx:I had to make a change to the Date regular expression, as my regional settings was configured to English(India), wherein DateTime is specified as DD-MM-YYYY HH:MI:SS (IST). I had to change this, since I got a Format invalid:System.DateTime exception during the run.

TimeOut:Specify the timeout for StarTeam polling.

Following is the complete listing of the starteam configuration block.
StarTeam

StarTeam

MSBuild section

I used MsBuild for the build task. Following section explains the properties involved to get the MsBuild setup for CruiseControl.Net.

Executable:Path to the ‘MsBuild.exe’ file in the system.

Working Directory:Location of the files to be built. i.e., Location to where the StarTeam extracted the files that need to be built.

Project File:The .proj file or the .sln file that needs to be built.

Build Args:Specifies additional arguments passed to the msbuild.exe.

Targets:Actions to be done. Here I wanted Clean’ and then ‘Build’ done on the Solution.

Timeout:Time after which error message will be displayed if there happens to be a failure to invoke the build.

Logger:Location of the logger assembly that will be used to produce the build result.

Following is the complete listing of the msbuild configuration block.
MS Build

MS Build

Triggers Section

Triggers section specifies the time and condition when the build of the project had to be invoked. During intital setup for testing, set the buildCondition to “ForceBuild” (forces a build), and once the testing is done, change it to “IfModificationExists”(does a build only when a modification is detected).

Following is the complete listing of the Triggers configuration block.
Triggers

Triggers

Step 5:Run the ccnet.exe application located in the ’server’ folder of the CruiseControl.Net install location. The code will be pulled from the StarTeam to the location specified and the build should proceed. The results of the build are stored in the $InstallFolder\ProjectName\Artifacts\ms-build.xml file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not surprised, I've used Star Team once and I can only say that the level of crap I had to get used to in that repository tool has only been surpassed ever in my entire programming career by Source Safe...

Don't use Star Team, if I were to start a big new project today I'd probably use GIT...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Change project setting in config file

> `<project>DEL_CA_ROBOTS\Tools\CCNet17Nov08</project>`

to

```
  <project>Project_name\View_name</project>
   <path>StarteamFolderName</path>
```

For example, if your project name is `DEL_CA_ROBOTS` and view name is also `DEL_CA_ROBOTS`
, script should be something like ..

```
   <project>DEL_CA_ROBOTS\DEL_CA_ROBOTS</project>
   <path>Tools\CCNet17Nov08</path>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

have you ever tried to set the culture to `<culture>en-US</culture>` if possible with starteam?

I had the same problem using Visual Source Safe. The only problem was that the culture was not set correctly.

Cheers.