# Cruise Control CCNET string not recognied as valid DateTime

Tags: datetime, tfs, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I'm write ccnet.config file that should build my project on every checkin on TFS source control server. When I run ccnet.exe, after i chekin something I got this error: Source control failure (GetModifications): string not recognied as valid DateTime. I thought that the problem is in my computer date format, so I change it like that [screenshot of my windows date format setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2RrV.png)

Nothing changes. Then i saw this
[post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/305087/6681786)

and think that maybe I should provide regular expression for Date in fileHistoryRegEx tag. But when i pasted in config file default regular expression that finded on

github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET/blob/master/project/core/sourcecontrol/StarTeam.cs
like

```html
<fileHistoryRegEx>^Revision: (?&lt;file_revision&gt;\S+) View: (?&lt;view_name&gt;.+) Branch Revision: (?&lt;branch_revision&gt;\S+).\nAuthor: (?&lt;author_name&gt;.*) Date: (?&lt;date_string&gt;.*) \w+\r\n(?&lt;change_comment&gt;.*)</fileHistoryRegEx>
```

or regular expression that was suggested on

cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/StarTeam

like

```html
<fileHistoryRegEx>?m:Revision: (?&lt;file_revision&gt;\S+) View: (?&lt;view_name&gt;.+) Branch Revision: (?&lt;branch_revision&gt;\S+)Author: (?&lt;author_name&gt;.*?) Date: (?&lt;date_string&gt;\d{01,2}/\d{1,2}/\d\d \d{1,2}:\d\d:\d\d (A|P)M).*\n(?s:(?&lt;change_comment&gt;.*?))-{28}</fileHistoryRegEx>
```

that gives me exception "unsed code detected" on this node.

This is my config file.

```html
<cruisecontrol xmlns:cb="urn:ccnet.config.builder">
<project name="WebApplication">
<workingDirectory>C:\Users\Ilovemycat\Source\Workspaces\Selukova\Development\WebApplication\</workingDirectory>
<artifactDirectory>C:\Users\Ilovemycat\Source\Workspaces\Selukova\Development\WebApplication\BuildArtifacts\</artifactDirectory>
<webURL>http://localhost/ccnet/ViewFarmReport.aspx</webURL>
<modificationDelaySeconds>30</modificationDelaySeconds>
<sourcecontrol type="vsts" autoGetSource="true" applyLabel="false">
<executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe</executable>
<server>server</server>
<username>username</username>
<password>password</password>
<domain>domain</domain>
<project>$/Selukova/Development/WebApplication</project>
<workingDirectory>C:\Users\Ilovemycat\Source\Workspaces\Selukova\Development\WebApplication\</workingDirectory>
<cleanCopy>false</cleanCopy>
<workspace>WS-STUDENT12</workspace>
<culture>en-US</culture>
<deleteWorkspace>false</deleteWorkspace>
</sourcecontrol>
<triggers>
<intervalTrigger name="continuous" seconds="30" buildCondition="IfModificationExists" initialSeconds="30"/>
</triggers>
<tasks>
<msbuild>
<executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MsBuild.exe</executable>
<workingDirectory>C:\Users\Ilovemycat\Source\Workspaces\Selukova\Development\WebApplication\</workingDirectory>
 <projectFile>WebApplication\WebApplication.sln</projectFile>
  <buildArgs>/p:Configuration=Debug /v:diag</buildArgs>
  <targets>Build;Test</targets>
  <timeout>30</timeout>
  <logger>C:\Program Files (x86)\CruiseControl.NET\server\ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.MSBuild.dll</logger>
</msbuild>
</tasks>
</project>

</cruisecontrol>
```

Comment: CC.Net is on a dead-end alley, more than two years without updates; are you sure using it?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Can you make a successful check-in without running ccnet.exe? Are you able to check in with TF.exe command line?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I install Windows 10 instead of Windows 7, set English language of Windows interface (initially it was Russian) and change my [region formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4coL9.png) .

The error disappeared.